# I cannot submit a job on HPC (QSUB)

Tags: hpc, qsub

for the past 2 months, I have been trying to find out why why I cannot submit a job on our HPC (using QSUB), recently, I found out that my home directory was

```
$/export/home/wrfuser

while my other co-workers are
$/home/wrfuser1

*note /export
```

I can submit a job but it never shows a result. Here's my sample hello.qsub:

---

```
#!/bin/bash --login
 #PBS -j oe
 #PBS -l walltime=00:01:00,nodes=1,ppn=1,mem=50mb

 export WORKDIR=/mnt/NFS003/WRF/WRF_hist/qsub_test

 cd ${WORKDIR}

 echo "HELLO WORLD"
```

---

```
[wrfuser@HPC qsub_test]$ vi hello.qsub

[wrfuser@HPC qsub_test]$ qsub hello.qsub
```

Your job 7618 ("hello.qsub") has been submitted

[wrfuser@HPC qsub_test]$ qstat

### job-ID  prior   name       user         state submit/start at     queue                          slots ja-task-ID

7617 0.55500 hello.qsub wrfuser      Eqw   04/06/2018 10:21:35                                    1
   7618 0.55500 hello.qsub wrfuser      Eqw    04/06/2018 10:35:15                                    1

[wrfuser@HPC qsub_test]$

If its not possible to do that on /export/home, is there any other way to submit a job on HPC?

Comment: Does your user have write permission to dirctory `/mnt/NFS003/WRF/WRF_hist/qsub_test`?

Comment: yes! It does, terry.qiao, Thanks!
Do you know how can I add a permission on a folder without access to the root?

Comment: if you are not the owner of target folder, then you can't (except you are root).

Comment: Thank you terry!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!!! I changed my qsub script to

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -pe orte 64


echo "HELLO JOHN"
mkdir Hello_world
[wrfuser@CADHPC01 run]$
```

I am using number of nodes,ppn, and memory on my previous script and now I changed it to number of cores `#$ -pe orte 64`. However, I not 100% sure that it is the main reason for that error.

I am newbie here in stackoverflow and it feels like I will learn and enjoy exponentially here!! Thanks! :D